# Install libwapiti for python on windows

Tags: python, cygwin, babun

I am trying to install libwapiti python binding on Windows but it look impossible. It installs seamlessly on Linux. I used [Babun](http://babun.github.io/) and [gccwinbinaries](https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries), but it did not work. What can I do?

Comment: it will help to git your error msg

Comment: Are you seeing error during installation of module or importing the module? Please post the error message. Also post which version of python you are using?

Comment: [The error message](http://textuploader.com/d538s). It happens when installing the library, as the error message says.

Comment: Isn't there any way?